# Extract Data from a page using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, data-extraction

I'd like to extract all the ISBNs on a dynamic web page that I can't feed through a Yahoo Pipe (the user has to log in to see the page). Is there a way to do that with jQuery? How?

**Edit:** 
The structure:

Here's an example of what the HTML looks like on that page. There's a `<table>` that has a series of `<tr>` elements in them. A sample one of those looks roughly like this:

```
<tr> 
  <td>(required/optional)</td>
  <td>LAFORE</td>
  <td>OBJECT ORIENTED PROGRAMMING IN C++ 4E</td>
  <td>9780672323089</td>
  <td>(course and section)</td>
  <td>(pricing information)</td>
</tr>
```

There are no id attributes on any of these, the structure is well defined though.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a sample of what the HTML and/or ISBNs you're working with?

Comment: I'll see if I can get one up here, but as a thought, could I just use Jquery's .text() attribute to give me all the text of the selected DOM element?

Comment: If the page has a known structure, you could run selectors and call `text()` to get the ISBN. Otherwise, you will have to use regular expressions and basically search on the entire page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//ideally provide better table selector if multiple tables are there
var isbns = $.makeArray($("table tr td:nth-child(4)"));
for(var i in isbns) {
  isbns[i] = isbns[i].innerHTML;
  alert(isbns[i]);
}
//now isbns is an array which contains all isbns found in the table
```